# Pole point on the Bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, bloch-sphere

If the state of the qubit is a point at a pole on the Bloch sphere, does this mean that the coefficient of the component corresponding to the other pole is zero?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for the pole it is directly opposite to; but not for all poles, notice how

$$| +\hat{z} \rangle=1|+\hat{z}\rangle + 0|-\hat{z}\rangle$$

But we can also say:

$$| +\hat{z} \rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2} |+\hat{x}\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|-\hat{x}\rangle$$

Comment: Following your logic, isn't *any* point a pole?